# Display columns headers on each page inside a PDF document using ItextSharp in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, itext

I've been using this guide to create PDF reporting: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC3

Basically I have a form that once it's submitted, It creates and opens a PDF report
the report is actually a view, for example this one:

```
@using MvcReportGeneratorDemo.Models
@model CustomerList
<br />
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    `<tr border="1" bgcolor="#777777" color="#ffffff">`
       <td>Name</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>Place</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (Customer customer in Model)
    {
        <tr border="1">
            <td>@customer.Name</td>
            <td>@customer.Address</td>
            <td>@customer.Place</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I want that each page in the PDF will have columns headers, not just the first one.
tried google but found nothing relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code at server side to solve your problem.

```
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(html))
        {

            foreach (IElement el in iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, null))
            {

                if (el is PdfPTable)
                {
                    ((PdfPTable)el).HeaderRows = 1;
                }
                doc.Add(el);
            }
        }
```